# why this code doesnt work and I cant expire the cookie?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, web

Hello the *expire* button is not working! whats the problem?
I want to expire the cookie when the user clicks the *expire* button.
please tell me the problem and the correct form of the code.Please tell me the reason!
I recently started php so Idont know much things aboat it.please explain it very simple.
I also added the codes and the picture!
[imag_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0285.png)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input placeholder="Cookie name" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="name">
            <input placeholder="Cookie value" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="value">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $Cookiename = $_POST["name"];
        $Cookievalue = $_POST["value"];
        if (!empty($Cookiename) && !empty($Cookievalue)) {
            setcookie($Cookiename, $Cookievalue);
        } else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Please fill the fields!!!</div>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <body class="container">

        <table class="table table-light">

            <thead class="thead-light">

                <tr>

                    <th>Cookie name</th>

                    <th>cookie value</th>

                    <th></th>

                </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <?php foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $val) { ?>

                    <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $key ?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $val ?></td>

                        <td><form method="POST"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="expire" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">expire</button></form></td>

                    </tr>

                <?php } ?>

            </tbody>


        </table>
    </body>


</html>


<?php
if (isset($_GET["expire"])) {
    setcookie('$_POST["expire"]','', time() - 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999);
    echo '$_POST["expire"]'.'is deleted!';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use single quotes in `'$_POST["expire"]'`? That won't resolve `$_POST["expire"]`

Comment: `isset($_GET["expire"]` is it `$_GET`?

Comment: @kerbholz Thank you! I corrected these things but I have this error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\pouyakaveh.training\index.php:66) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pouyakaveh.training\index.php on line 84`

Comment: From [the setcookie documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php): "_setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers._" ... Do not send any output before sending headers